# How can I best manage a teething puppy?

Tags: health, dogs, teething

My puppy is 4.5 months old, and he's teething. His gums are quite red and irritated.

I provide him with different chew toys (only 1-2 of them at the same time, changing every day). I also give him a [stuffed frozen Kong](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/what-kind-of-food-should-i-stuff-into-a-kong) in the afternoon and a frozen [Kong puppy teething stick](http://www.kongcompany.com/zh-hans/products/for-dogs/rubber-toys/puppy-rubber/puppy-teething-stick/).

- Am I doing the right thing?
- Is there anything else I can do?
- Is teething painful for the puppy, and if so, how can we manage the discomfort and pain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have lots of things that are appropriate for the puppy to chew like sturdy rubber toys, bones, and you can even give cold carrots. When the puppy shows interest in something that is off limits redirect them to one of the items they should chew. Don't allow the puppy access to places with things they shouldn't chew without supervision, crate training is invaluable for this and many other reasons. And have patience, this stage will pass.