# What are good fillings for a Kong?

Tags: dogs, treats

Our Sheltie puppy loves his peanut butter Kong treats, which he gets every few days (one a week perhaps less) but because peanut butter is high in fats, sugars etc, we don't want him to get chubby as his breed is prone to easily becoming overweight, however peanut butter keeps him occupied for a good half hour - hour.

He has two Kongs, one is a pink large breed puppy Kong gifted to us by a friend whose dog outgrew it, and the other is a blue small breed puppy Kong. The blue one gets his peanut butter in, the other sometimes gets his regular food in, dinner or breakfast, but he'll often get bored of this. He also refuses to eat his kibble mushy, we've tried this in his Kong too.

I know you can purchase the official Kong fillings (but these are rather expensive) so I was wondering if anyone had had decent sucess with other various Kong fillings?

Comment: @Cedric Looks good, nothing came up when I searched on the app before, doh! But unfortunately he won't eat mushy kibble, what worked for you in the end?

Comment: Semi-liquid home cooked food or a bunch of treats (pieces of chicken, commercial treats and kibble) "sealed" with peanut butter or the filling sold by Kong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of food should I stuff into a Kong?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/what-kind-of-food-should-i-stuff-into-a-kong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carrots! They're awesome for your dogs teeth, not high in calories, and a good source of vitamins. Chop them up in different sizes and use a larger one to hold them in. You can even put some pumpkin or sweet potato chunks to add flavor and softer texture, but use sparingly as sweet potatoes have a higher calorie content.

Answer (score 3):

Biscuits to bulk it out it, meat paste (pate) to glue it together, then freeze it. It'll occupy your dog for hours.